# Spring boot rest api to update the columns

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I'm working with Spring-boot and Mysql .i have a class with 50 Properties which are referring 50 columns in mysql table with primary key and foreign key relationship. and i have to write a single api to update the multiple fields ,that fields can be any-one and any number of fields according to request from end .
can anyone please guide me or give me and idea like how to write that update api and what will be the param of url ,whether i have to use path param or query param, what will be the steps, using spring boot and mysql databases.

Comment: It should be a POST API since you are updating the DB so no question of request params or path params. You can use hibernate at the backend. I guess the class with 50 properties you are talking about here is the entity class?

Answer (score 1):

You need controller like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myobject")
public class MyObjectController {

    ...

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> update(@PathVariable int id, MyObjectDTO myObjectDTO) {
        myObjectService.update(id, myObjectDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need write a custom service method using Criteria API for this task. Please refer to Criteria API documentation of the ORM you are using. Also if you are just updating the data then just updating the values in the object and calling save() method should work fine.